# How can prime numbers be identified through characteristics of matrix/grid structures formed by polyhedra?

Tags: geometry, prime-numbers, polyhedra, twin-primes, semiprimes

Have you come across a similar theory to predict prime numbers?

I believe that I have identified a pattern by which prime numbers occur which is in the form:
N = A(P,n) + B

…where A is a function of a multi-symmetrical shape (polyhedron) P and B is the adjusting function. The n defines the size (order) of the matrix of the multi-symmetrical shape. The pattern of observations is that A(P,n) leads close to the prime number N (please read an example further down) whereas B steps up/down to N by a small integer.

By a multi-symmetrical shape (P) is meant a matrix structure of tetrahedra, cubes, isocahedra. The function A is a characteristic of the multi-symmetrical geometric shape in eg a tetrahedron matrix of 1, 4, 10, 20, 35, etc tetrahedra inside or a cube matrix of 1, 8, 27, 64, 125 etc cubes inside.

I introduce the theory in this forum to check if similar theories have been up for scrutinization. In my research so far, I have not found anything similar, ie *using matrix/grid structures of multi-symmetrical geometric shapes as the basis for finding and defining prime numbers*.

First some background to the reasoning applied to take it from an idea to a theory:

- The logarithmic relation between prime numbers (as in the prime number theorem) indicates a relation of something “natural”.
- My MSc degree in engineering physics many years ago specialized in crystalline structures, and this inspired me to explore the relationship between prime numbers and characteristics of matrix/grid structures which are built by tetrahedrons, cubes, isocaeders, etc (ie multi-symmetric geometric shapes).
- The occurrence of prime numbers in nature (built on the theories of physics) such as observations of cicadas appearing in cycles of a prime number of years also pointed at a relationship between prime numbers and something in nature, such molecular structures.

The general form of the pattern described as N = A(P,n) + B includes N-series for each multi-symmetrical shape, eg N[tetrahedron], N[cube], etc. In other words:

- Going through characteristics of tetrahedron based matrices with 1,…, n “layers” leads to one series of prime numbers
- Going through characteristics of cube based matrices with 1,…, n layers leads to another series of prime numbers
- Going through characteristics of other symmetrical shapes leads to other series

…forming separate ‘families’ of prime numbers

So a prime number can be found by a combination of:

a/ A function which represents characteristics of multi-symmetrical geometrical shapes, e.g. a tetrahedron structure

b/ An ‘adjusting’ function which adds or subtracts a certain number of steps/integers from (a)

The number of nodes and connections/lattices between the nodes are part of the theory/hypothesis and what I mean by *characteristics* of the matrix structures. For tetrahedron shapes the first/simplest matrix has 1 node, the second an additional 3 nodes, the third an additional 6 nodes, the fourth and additional 10 nodes, etc. For cube matrices/grids, the first matrix has 1 node, the second and additional 7 nodes, the third an additional 19 nodes, the fourth an additional 37 nodes, etc. To continue this cube matrix based series described as A(cube,n) = (n+1)(n+1)(n+1) – n x n x n , A equates to 7, 19, 37, 61, 91, 127, 169, 217, 271, 331, 397, 469, 547, 631, 721, 817 and 919, of which all are primes except the semi-primes 91 (7x13), 169 (13x13), 469 (7x67), 721 (7x103) and 817 (19x43).

So in the case of the **“ A(cube,n) = (n+1)(n+1)(n+1) – n x n x n ”** equation, “n” represents the size, or order, of the cube matrix structure. Accordingly, A(cube,n) can be described *using matrix/grid based terminology* as the number of **additional nodes required to form the next (larger) order** of a cube matrix structure. This *representation*, referring to multi-symmetrical **geometric shapes**, exemplifies the more over-arching fundamental theory that prime numbers can be defined as a function of geometrical shapes in nature; in this case a cube-based matrix structure.

For those of you who find this theory plausible and worthwhile working further on, I would be happy to share more details of my findings and observations so far. The theory does need further work, eg to specify how the adjusting function B behaves. If you recognise the above hypothesis from before (and I do not mean models like Ulam spirals or Klauber triangle), please share. Cuban Primes would be one "family" of several, and the other families relate to other polyhedra and crystal grit/matrix structures.

. . . . . . . . . . . . .

Comment: Your "matrix structure" idea seems be getting at "polyhedral numbers"; eg, [cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_(algebra)) and [tetrahedrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number). (I can't tell if your "icosaeders" are [icosahedrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_number).) If you're asking whether one can generate (some? many? all?) primes from these #s (w/"adjustment"), I can only note that, since polyhedral #s are just polynomials in $n$, the question falls into the well-studied field of prime-generating polynomials ... about which I know next-to-nothing. :)

Comment: Just so we're a little clearer on terminology, please provide the first few sample values for an "icosahedron matrix" (like you did for the tetrahedral and cube matrices). Are they, in fact, the [icosahedral numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_number)?